# how add html5 new tag into my html

Tags: html, css

hi guys sry for my bad english.

my master said to me i have to add html5 tags like header,footer,main and etc into my html file. but when i add for example header tag my page will messed up.

can anyone add this tags into my index.html or answer me what do i have to do for add these tags ? thanks a lot.

```
plnkr.co/KLYxwSD8WE6RwXcntQlg
```

```js
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
header{
 margin:auto;
 padding:0px;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
#main{
 width:1200px;
 height:1865px;
 margin:auto;
 background-color:#FFF;
}

#menu{
 width:1200px; 
 height:52px;
 background-color:#222222;
 
}
#logo{
 float:left;
 padding-left:30px;
 padding-top:12px; 
}
#menu ul li {
 float:left;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#9e9e9c;
 padding-left:23px;
 padding-top:15px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 padding-right:25px;
 display:inline-block;
 position: relative;
 
}
#menu ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#9e9e9c;
}
#menu ul li a:hover{
 color:#FFF;
 
}
#menu ul li:hover{
 background: #000; 
}
#menu ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
 min-width:110px;
 height:auto;
 background-color:#000;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:-25px;
 
}
#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
 
 
}
#search{
 float:right;
 padding-top:8px;
 padding-right:30px;
}
#search input[type=text]{
 width:195px;
 height:34px;
 border-radius:3px;
 border:none; 
}
#search input[type=submit]{
 width:71px;
 height:34px;
 border-radius:3px;
 border:none;
 color:#333335; 
}
#header{
 height:294px;
 width:1200px;
 background-color:#9acd32; 
}
#header-logo{
 padding-top:72px;
 padding-left:29px;
 float:left; 
}
#header-title{
 color:#adff30;
 float:left;
 padding-top:80px;
 padding-left:26px;
 font-size:65px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
#header-txt{
 color:#adff30;
 float:left;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding-top:30px;
 padding-left:29px;
 font-size:20px;
 width:1200px;
}
#engage{
 float:left;
 padding-top:30px;
 padding-left:29px;
 
}
#engage input[type=button]{
 width:106px;
 height:34px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border:none;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:#333335;
}
#body{
 width:1200px;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
}
#body-header{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size:36px;
 padding-left:34px;
 padding-top:76px;
 float:left;
}
#body-header-text{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:25px;
 padding-left:13px;
 padding-top:85px;
 float:left;
 color:#333335;
}
#body-txt{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:15px;
 color:#333335;
 float:left;
 padding-left:34px;
 padding-top:36px; 
}
.body-news{
 width:374px; 
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 
}
#body-news-left{
 float:left;
 margin-left:26px;
 margin-top:18px;
}
#body-news-right{
 float:left;
 margin-left:37px;
 margin-top:18px;
}
.news-pic{
 width:359px;
 height:300px;
 padding-left:8px;
  
}
.news-title{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#3379b7;
 font-size:20px;
 padding-top:23px;
 padding-left:8px;
 width:auto;
 height:auto; 
}
.news-brieftxt{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 color:#333335;
 font-size:13px;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-left:8px;
 line-height:17px;
}
#contact-form{
 width:379px;
 height:auto;
 float:right;
 margin-top:18px;
 margin-left:10px; 
}
#contact-from-title{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#333335;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-left:10px; 
}
.input{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 color:#333335;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:14px; 
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-top:15px;
}
.input input[type=text]{

 border:1px solid;
 border-color:#CCCCCC;
 width:326px;
 height:37px;
 border-radius:4px;
 margin-top:3px;
 
}
.input input[type=email]{

 border:1px solid;
 border-color:#CCCCCC;
 width:326px;
 height:37px;
 border-radius:4px;
 margin-top:3px;
 
}
.input input[type=password]{

 border:1px solid;
 border-color:#CCCCCC;
 width:326px;
 height:37px;
 border-radius:4px;
 margin-top:3px;
 
}
.input input[type=submit]{

 border:1px solid;
 border-color:#CCCCCC;
 width:326px;
 height:37px;
 border-radius:4px;
 margin-top:3px;
 
}
#forgot{
 padding-top:12px;
 padding-left:10px; 
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#2b82ec;
}
#forgot a{
 color:#2b82ec;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:600;
}
#remember input[type=checkbox]{
 margin-top:12px;
 margin-left:10px;
 float:left; 
}
#remember-txt{
 margin-top:11px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#333335;
 float:left;
 width:290px;
  
}
#login input[type=submit]{
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-"Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
 font-size:13px;
 width:94px;
 height:36px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#43a047;
 border:1px solid;
 border-color:#CCCCCC;
 border-radius:4px;
 margin-top:12px;
 margin-left:17px;
}
#article{
 width:1200px;
 height:auto; 
 background-color:#daa521;
 margin-top:15px;
 float:left;
 
}
.article-class{
 width:353px;
 height:274px;
 margin-top:58px;  
}
#article-left{
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px; 
}
#article-center{
 float:left;
 margin-left:40px;
}
#article-right{
 float:right;
 margin-right:30px;
}
.article-logo{
 width:31px;
 height:33px;
 float:left; 
}
.article-title{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:20px;
 padding-top:4px; 
}
.article-txt{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 color:#010005;
 font-size:16px;
 line-height:22px;
 float:left;
}
.article-button input[type=button]{
 margin-top:20px;
 padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 height:35px;
 width:auto; 
 border:1px solid;
 border-color:#CCCCCC;
 border-radius:4px;
}
#table{
 float:left;
 margin-top:45px;
 margin-left:44px;
 width:1114px; 
}
#first-row{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#FFF; 
 background-color:#daa521;
 width:1113px;
 height:58px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float:left;
 font-size:14px;
 border-top-left-radius:4px;
 border-top-right-radius:4px;
}
#no{
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-left:37px;
 padding-right:128px; 
}
#name{
 padding-right:100px; 
}
#age{
 padding-right:96px; 
}
#job{
 padding-right:105px; 
}
#birth{
 padding-right:90px; 
}
#id{
 padding-right:90px; 
 
}
#grade{
 padding-right:80px; 
 
}
.rows{
 width:1113px; 
 height:42px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 float:left;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
}
.no{
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-left:37px;
 padding-right:128px;  
 
}
.name{
 padding-left:14px;
 padding-right:124px; 
}
.age{
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-right:75px; 
 
}
.job{
 padding-right:82px; 
}
.birth{
 padding-right:70px; 
}
.id{
 padding-right:80px; 
}
.action a{
 text-decoration:none;
}

.action {
 padding-left:70px;
 margin-top:15px;
}
#footer{
 float:left;
 width:1200px;
 height:auto;
}
#links{
 margin-top:40px;
 margin-left:470px; 
 
}
#links a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#3279b7;
 font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:15px; 
}
#copyright{
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-left:530px;
 font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:11px;
 color:#999;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Project 1</title>
<link href="Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<header>
 <div id="main">
     <div id="menu">
         <div id="logo">
             <img src="Images/logo.png" width="66" height="26" />
            </div><!--logo-->
            <ul id="main-menu">
             <li><a href="a">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="a">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="a">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="a">Services</a>
                 <ul class="sub-menu">
                     <li><a href="a">service 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="a">service 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="a">service 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="a">service 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="search">
             <input type="text" name="text" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search"/>
            </div><!--search-->
        </div><!--menu-->
</header>
        <div id="header">
         <div id="header-logo">
             <img src="Images/header.png" width="65" height="62" />
         </div><!--header-logo-->
            <div id="header-title">
             Dramatically Engage
            </div><!--header-title-->
            <div id="header-txt">
             Objectively innovate empowered manufactured products whereas parallel platforms.
            </div><!--header-txt-->
            <div id="engage">
             <input type="button" value="Engage now" />
            </div><!--engage-->
        </div><!--header-->
        </header>
        <div id="body">
         <div id="body-header">
             Superior Collaboration
         </div><!--body-header-->
            <div id="body-header-text">
             Visualize Quality
            </div><!--body-header-text-->
            <div id="body-txt">
             Proactively envisioned multimedia based expertise and cross-media growth strategies. Seamlessly visualize quality                      intellectal capital without superior collaboration and idea-sharing.Holistically ponitificate installed base                portals after maintainable products
            </div><!--body-txt-->
            <div id="body-news-left" class="body-news">
             <div class="news-pic">
                 <img src="Images/news-pic.png" width="359" height="300" />
                </div><!--news-pic-->
                <div class="news-txt">
                 <div class="news-title">
                     Efficiently Unleash
                    </div><!--news-title-->
                    <div class="news-brieftxt">
                     Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks.Dynamically procrastinate B2C
                        users after installed base benefits.Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without                        revolutionary ROI.
                    </div><!--news-brieftxt-->
                </div><!--news-txt-->
            </div><!--body-news-left-->
            <div id="body-news-right" class="body-news">
             <div class="news-pic">
                 <img src="Images/news-pic.png" width="359" height="300" />
                </div><!--news-pic-->
                <div class="news-txt">
                 <div class="news-title">
                     Completely Synergize
                    </div><!--news-title-->
                    <div class="news-brieftxt">
                     Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions.Efficiently unleash cross-medi
                        information without cross-media value.Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas.
                    </div><!--news-brieftxt-->
                </div><!--news-txt-->
            </div><!--body-news-right-->
            <div id="contact-form">
             <div id="contact-from-title">
                 Contact form
                </div>
                <form action="#" method="post" >
                <div id="name" class="input">
                 Name:<br />
                    <input type="text" />
                </div><!--name-->
                <div id="email" class="input">
                 Email:<br />
                    <input type="email" />
                </div><!--email-->
                <div id="password" class="input">
                 Password:<br />
                    <input type="password" />
                </div><!--password-->
                <div id="forgot">
                 <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                </div><!--forgot-->
                <div id="remember">
                 <input type="checkbox" />
                 <div id="remember-txt">Remember</div>
                </div><!--remember-->
                </div><!--contact-form-->
                <div id="login"><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" />
                </div><!--login-->
                </form>
            
        </div><!--body-->
        <div id="article">
         <div id="article-left" class="article-class">
             <div class="article-logo">
                 <img src="Images/article-logo1.png" width="26" height="28" />
                </div><!--article-logo-->
                <div class="article-title">
                 Dynamically Procrastinate
                </div><!--article-title-->
                <div class="article-txt">
                 Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users
                    after installed base benefits.Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI.
                </div><!--article-txt-->
                <div class="article-button">
                 <input type="button" value="Procrastinate"/>
                </div><!--article-button-->
            </div><!--article-left-->
         <div id="article-center" class="article-class">
             <div class="article-logo">
                 <img src="Images/article-logo2.png" width="29" height="28" />
                </div><!--article-logo-->
                <div class="article-title">
                 Efficently Unleash
                </div><!--article-title-->
                <div class="article-txt">
                 Dramatically maintain click-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions. Efficiently unleash cross-media
                    information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time                                 schmas.Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks.
                </div><!--article-txt-->
                <div class="article-button">
                 <input type="button" value="Unleash"/>
                </div><!--article-button-->
            </div><!--article-center-->
        <div id="article-right" class="article-class">
             <div class="article-logo">
                 <img src="Images/article-logo3.png" width="31" height="33" />
                </div><!--article-logo-->
                <div class="article-title">
                 Completely Synergize
                </div><!--article-title-->
                <div class="article-txt">
                 Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Completely synergize resource taxing
                    relationships via premier niche markets. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state
                    of the art customer service.
                </div><!--article-txt-->
                <div class="article-button">
                 <input type="button" value="synergize"/>
                </div><!--article-button-->
            </div><!--article-right-->
        </div><!--article-->
        <div id="table">
               <table width="1114" >
                   <thead>
                      <tr id="first-row">
                        <th id="no">No</th>
                        <th id="name">Name and Family</th>
                        <th id="age">Age</th>
                        <th id="job">Job</th>
                        <th id="birth">Birthday</th>
                        <th id="id">ID NO.</th>
                        <th id="grade">Grade</th>
                        <th id="action">Action</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr class="rows">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="name">Hashem Dick</td>
                    <td class="age">13</td>
                    <td class="job">Dick blower</td>
                    <td class="birth">2016/8/19</td>
                    <td class="id">6598-1425</td>
                    <td class="grade">bachelor</td>
                    <td class="action"><a href="#"><img  src="Images/action1.png" /></a><a href="#">
                    <img  src="Images/action2.png" /></a></td>
                   </tr>
                  <tr class="rows">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="name">Hashem Dick</td>
                    <td class="age">13</td>
                    <td class="job">Dick blower</td>
                    <td class="birth">2016/8/19</td>
                    <td class="id">6598-1425</td>
                    <td class="grade">bachelor</td>
                    <td class="action"><a href="#"><img src="Images/action1.png" /></a><a href="#">
                    <img src="Images/action2.png" /></a></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="rows">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="name">Hashem Dick</td>
                    <td class="age" >13</td>
                    <td class="job">Dick blower</td>
                    <td class="birth">2016/8/19</td>
                    <td class="id">6598-1425</td>
                    <td class="grade">bachelor</td>
                    <td class="action"><a href="#"><img src="Images/action1.png" /></a><a href="#">
                    <img src="Images/action2.png" /></a></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="rows">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="name">Hashem Dick</td>
                    <td class="age">13</td>
                    <td class="job">Dick blower</td>
                    <td class="birth">2016/8/19</td>
                    <td class="id">6598-1425</td>
                    <td class="grade">bachelor</td>
                    <td class="action"><a href="#"><img src="Images/action1.png" /></a><a href="#">
                    <img src="Images/action2.png" /></a></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="rows">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="name">Hashem Dick</td>
                    <td class="age">13</td>
                    <td class="job">Dick blower</td>
                    <td class="birth">2016/8/19</td>
                    <td class="id">6598-1425</td>
                    <td class="grade">bachelor</td>
                    <td class="action"><a href="#"><img src="Images/action1.png" /></a><a href="#">
                    <img src="Images/action2.png" /></a></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="rows">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="name">Hashem Dick</td>
                    <td class="age">13</td>
                    <td class="job">Dick blower</td>
                    <td class="birth">2016/8/19</td>
                    <td class="id">6598-1425</td>
                    <td class="grade">bachelor</td>
                    <td class="action"><a href="#"><img src="Images/action1.png" /></a><a href="#">
                    <img src="Images/action2.png" /></a></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="rows">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="name">Hashem Dick</td>
                    <td class="age">13</td>
                    <td class="job">Dick blower</td>
                    <td class="birth">2016/8/19</td>
                    <td class="id">6598-1425</td>
                    <td class="grade">bachelor</td>
                    <td class="action"><a href="#"><img src="Images/action1.png" /></a><a href="#">
                    <img src="Images/action2.png" /></a></td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
            </table>
   </div><!--table-->
        <footer id="footer">
         <div id="links">
             <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>| <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>|<a href="#">Contact</a>
         </div><!--links-->
            <div id="copyright">
             Copyright © Examples.com 2015
            </div>
        </footer><!--footer-->
    </div><!--main-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use indecent words in a forum like this, i removed that.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Because `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the doctype declaration for HTML5.

Comment: i did what u said but nothing happened and when i add <header> tag into my html file that part of html that is between <header> tag will be separate from others.